# Magento 1.9.3 Capture payment without invoice?

Tags: payment-gateway, magento1.9.3, workflow

Is it possible to add a **Capture** button in **order view**? It seems Magento can only capture the payment when invoice is created. But I need to already Capture the payment when order is made.

Comment: Which Payment method you are using?

Answer (score 0):

https://schogini.ladesk.com/758922-How-do-I-capture-an-authorized-payment-via-the-Magento-admin-area

You can check these steps for how to set capture when order is created.